# Java equivalent to javascript map method with two parameters, with the second being the index

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, java-8

I Have the above example, written in Typescript:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let indicesOfOddNumbers = numbers
  .map((number, index) => {
    return {
      index, number
    }
  })
  .filter(a => a.number % 2 != 0)
  .map(a => a.index);
```

How Java would do something similar?

Comment: This is probably possible using Java streams.  Have you tried any Java code yet?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's like something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length)
         .mapToObj(x -> new SimpleEntry(x, numbers[x]))
         .filter(x -> x.getValue() % 2 == 0)
         .map(Entry::getKey)
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: First `map` should be `mapToObj`

Comment: @abetteroliver ups!

Answer (score 2):

A stream based solution that filters and maps in one step:

```
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length)
         .boxed()
         .flatMap(index -> numbers[index] % 2 != 0 ? of(index): empty())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`of` and `empty` are static members of `Stream`. What it does is checking if the number is odd and if it is, it returns the index otherwise it returns nothing. Well, actually it returns a stream but that is resolved by `flatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so,

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
List<Integer> indicesOfOddNumbers = IntStream.range(0, numbers.size())
        .filter(i -> numbers.get(i) % 2 != 0)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First create an int stream going from the beginning of the list to the end. Then get each element in the list via index and filter out any even numbers. After that box it into a boxed primitive before you collect it into a `List` as your last step.

Comment: Of course! You can filter the indices directly. I was confused at first about whether the OP wanted the numbers or indices so I started with `flatMap`. +1